# Only keep strings in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop all rows of my dataframe where the value in a row is not `str`

```
# example data
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 'test1'), (2, 'test2'), (3, 3.14)])
df.columns = ['row1', 'row2']
```

I came up with this solution, but is there a simpler, more pythonic way? Having to use `apply()` seems messy.

```
 df[df['row2'].apply(type) == str]
```

Comment: For rows that might contain the string representation of a number, maybe try `[isinstance(i, str) for i in df.row2]`.  Although now that's compromising efficiency, but it will beat `apply`

Comment: You can use isnumeric. `df[~df['row2'].str.isnumeric().fillna(True)]`